# Do I need to create a custom file context type for /etc/zabbix/ if I don't want to use unlabeled_t?

Tags: centos, selinux, zabbix

I have installed zabbix (a monitoring application) on a CentOS 7 machine. For security purposes, I want to leave selinux in enforced mode. Therefore I have to grant my zabbix a few permissions in order to work.
If I execute the following:

`ausearch -c zabbix_server -m AVC -i -ts today | audit2allow -m ztest`

I get the following output:

```
...
require {
     type unlabeled_t;
     type zabbix_var_run_t;
     type zabbix_t;
     class sock_file { create unlink };
     class unix_stream_socket connectto;
     class file { getattr open read };
}

#========== zabbix_t ==============

#!!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'daemons_enable_cluster_mode'
allow zabbix_t self:unix_stream_socket connectto;

#!!!!! WARNING 'unlabeled_t' is a base type.
allow zabbix_t unlabeled_t:file { getattr open read };
allow zabbix_t zabbix_var_run_t:sock_file { create unlink };
```

After a little research I found out that the /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf file has the file context type unlabeled_t, which is the reason why audit2allow suggests me to allow the unlabeled_t for the zabbix_server. But since it's a bad idea to allow a base type, I am searching for a way to solve this. I already looked in the zabbix_selinux manpage (https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-zabbix_selinux/), but there really is no appropiate context file type. I know, that I can create my own file context type, but I am not really an expert, so  I don't know if this is the best solution. So my Question is if there is better way or do I really need to create my own file context type if I don't want to use the base type unlabeled_t?

Comment: It looks like you omitted the relevant part of the generated policy. The `require` section only specifies what types should be there before the policy is loaded. Can you show the full policy that was generated? Checking on the default policy in EL7, the file you quote should be `system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0`. What happens if you run `restorecon -v /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`

Comment: @DanilaVershinin
Although I already got an answer, I edited my post to include the parts I omitted before. But I have to admit I don't really understand what you mean with 'The require section only specifies what types should be there before the policy is loaded'

Comment: You were right I used resorecon and it turns out the default type is etc_t. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably installed Zabbix from a SELinux-unaware source, or perhaps with SELinux disabled on installation.

If Zabbix was not installed from a SELinux-aware package, it is likely that running `restorecon -R -v /etc` would automatically change the `unlabeled_t` labels to something else, probably `etc_t`, as that seems to be the default label for files and directories under `/etc`. You should probably do that before using `audit2allow`.

`etc_t` would be a good context type for most configuration files.

The SELinux ruleset of RHEL/CentOS 7.x actually has some built-in provisions for Zabbix: directory `/etc/zabbix/web/` and any files in it will be labeled `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` and the startup scripts of Zabbix, both server and agent, will get appropriate labels of `zabbix_initrc_exec_t` and `zabbix_agent_initrc_exec_t`, respectively.

The following is from a "vanilla" RHEL 7.7 test VM with no Zabbix packages installed at all:

```
[root@localhost etc]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)

[root@localhost etc]# semanage fcontext -l |grep zabbix
/var/log/zabbix.*                                  all files          system_u:object_r:zabbix_log_t:s0 
/etc/zabbix/web(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 
/var/lib/zabbix(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:zabbix_var_lib_t:s0 
/var/run/zabbix(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:zabbix_var_run_t:s0 
/etc/rc\.d/init\.d/(zabbix|zabbix-server)          regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_initrc_exec_t:s0 
/var/lib/zabbixsrv(/.*)?                           all files          system_u:object_r:zabbix_var_lib_t:s0 
/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts(/.*)?              all files          system_u:object_r:zabbix_script_exec_t:s0 
/var/lib/zabbix/externalscripts(/.*)?              all files          system_u:object_r:zabbix_script_exec_t:s0 
/usr/bin/zabbix_server                             regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/usr/bin/zabbix_agentd                             regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_agent_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy                             regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd                            regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_agent_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_server                            regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy_mysql                       regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy_pgsql                       regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_server_mysql                      regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_server_pgsql                      regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/etc/rc\.d/init\.d/zabbix-agentd                   regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_agent_initrc_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy_sqlite3                     regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/zabbix_server_sqlite3                    regular file       system_u:object_r:zabbix_exec_t:s0
```

Comment: You were right I used resorecon and it turns out the default type is etc_t. Thanks a lot.